# What regex should I use to check a string only has numbers and 2 special characters ( - and , ) in Java?

Tags: java, regex

**Scenario**: I want to check whether string contains only numbers and 2 predefined special characters, a dash and a comma.

My string contains numbers (0 to 9) and 2 special characters: a dash (`-`) defines a range and a comma (`,`) defines a sequence.

**Tried attempt** :
Tried following regex `[0-9+-,]+`, but not working as expected.

**Possible inputs :**

```
1-5
1,5
1-5,6
1,3,5-10
1-5,6-10
1,3,5-7,8,10
```

The regex should not accept these types of strings:

```
-----
1--4
,1,5
5,6,
5,4,-
5,6-
-5,6
```

Please can any one help me to create regex for above scenario?

Comment: But your regex will match **more than these**: also things that do not make any sense...

Comment: What means `, but not working as expected`?

Comment: Have you tried this?: [[0-9+-],]+

Comment: @Jens **,  but not working as expected?**, means when I give above all possible inputs , it not checking where string contains only number with special characters , it is getting succeed if I use alphabets .

Comment: @JCalcines , thank you for response , the above given regex is working as expected . For alphabets it don't .

Comment: @Raks: Good, then your question needs updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^\d+(?:-\d+)?(?:,\d+(?:-\d+)?)*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jwsGxs/1)

**Regex details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `(?:-\d+)?` - an optional sequence of `-` and 1+ digits
- `(?:,\d+(?:-\d+)?)*` - zero or more seuqences of:

  - `,` - a comma
  - `\d+(?:-\d+)?` - same pattern as described above
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thank you very much @Wiktor Stribiżew , above regex works as expected . .

Comment: Just a note: since it is used in Java, when defining the pattern inside  a string literal, backslashes must be doubled.

Answer (score 0):

Change your regex [0-9+-,]+ to [0-9,-]+

```
final String patternStr = "[0-9,-]+";
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile(patternStr);
String data = "1,3,5-7,8,10";
final Matcher m = p.matcher(data);
if (m.matches()) {
System.out.println("SUCCESS");
}else{
System.out.println("ERROR");
}
```

Comment: Hi Raks, this is your question "I want to check whether string contains only numbers and 2 predefined special characters ( dash (-) and comma (,))." . As per the your question you want "only number and ( dash (-) and comma (,)).

Comment: @Raks: So, `-----` is a valid input?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew ,I did testing for all possible combinations  ,  the answer you provided is very relevant ,I re accepted . Thank you .